# Limits to infinity, even and odd functions

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have a couple of questions regarding a practice test I just made, so the subject might vary a little bit but most of it has to do with limits.

1. $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{7x+3x^2}{1-x^3} $$

Apparently this is $-3$, but I've read in my book that if a rational function has a higher order polynomial in the denominator, that the limit always becomes $0$. If this is false, how are you supposed to evaluate this limit?

2. $$ \lim_{x \to 1+} \dfrac{7x+3x^2}{1-x^3} $$

I just have no idea how to do this, right and left limits are very difficult to me unless I have the graph.

3. $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$ and $h(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$. What is the parity of $g$ and $h$. $f$ is a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$.

How are you supposed to do this without knowing the parity of $f$?

4. $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x-\sqrt{x^2+ax+b}} $$

$a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a\neq 0$.

I haven't worked with 2 variables yet, so I would appreciate a good tactic here.

Comment: For 4, you have only one variable, $x$.  You have two parameters, $a$ and $b$.  The difference is that your answer is supposed to be general in $a,b$ and not depend on $x$.  So you can imagine (for one solution) that $a$ and $b$ are some fixed numbers that I give you, but your answer may have $a$ and $b$ in it.  So if the problem were to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} (ax)^2+b(x+1)$ your answer would be $a^2+b$.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, the limit is indeed $0$.

For the second problem, imagine that $x$ is a tiny bit *bigger* than $1$. What can you say about $1-x^3$? What about $\frac{7x+3x^2}{1-x^3}$? It should be clear, but if it isn't, use your calculator with $x=1.00001$.

For the third problem, let us do half, showing that $h$ is even.
We have 
$$h(-x)=f(-x)+f(-(-x))=f(-x)+f(x)=h(x).$$

For the fourth problem, multiply top and bottom by $x+\sqrt{x^2+ax+b}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps for the first problem
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{7x+3x^2}{1-x^3}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{7x}{x^2}+\frac{3x^2}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{x^3}{x^2}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{7}{x}+3}{\frac{1}{x^2}-x}=\frac{\frac{7}{\infty}+3}{\frac{1}{\infty}-\infty}=-\frac{3}{\infty}=0
$$
For the second problem, we have
$$
\lim_{x \to 1+} \frac{7x+3x^2}{1-x^3}
$$
Since $1 \lt x^3$ as $x\to 1$ from the right, then the denominator is negative. This expression also has a vertical asymptote at $x=1$, therefore
$$
\lim_{x \to 1+} \frac{7x+3x^2}{1-x^3}=-\infty
$$
Give the others a shot and feel free to ask questions.